# How can I execute psexec commands in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, psexec

I am trying to write a bat file that will accomplish the following:

```
psexec \\host1 cmd
d: #to change the remote server's drive
cd\
dir /s/b "file1" #searches for this file in host1 in its d: drive
```

How can I go about doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a current day Windows system, you can invoke the command on a remote computer using PowerShell from within your cmd .bat script. No need for psexec. The remote machine does need to be setup for PowerShell remoting. `Get-Help about_Remote`

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "invoke-command HOST01 { cmd /C dir /S /B D:\file1 }"
```

If you are running in PowerShell:

```
invoke-command HOST01 { cmd /C dir /S /B D:\file1 }
```

Of course, in PowerShell you might as well use PowerShell cmdlets.

```
icm HOST01 { gci -n -rec D:\file1 }
    -or-
Invoke-Command HOST01 { Get-ChildItem -Name -Recurse D:\file1 }
```

Comment: many thanks for sharing , how can i include this powershell command in perl script

Comment: Nothing was said about Perl. Please create a new question.

Comment: i asked the question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634440/how-can-i-write-this-powershell-in-perl-script)

Answer (score 0):

```
psexec \\host1 cmd /c "d: & cd\ & dir /s/b file1"
```

or simply

```
psexec \\host1 cmd /c "dir /s/b d:\file1"
```

The console in which the `cmd` is executed is automatically closed when the command finishes executing, so you won't actually see the result. You could leave `cmd` running (and console along with it) by using `/k` instead of `/c`, but that doesn't make much sense either. You appear to have an XY problem.

Comment: It seems psexec reuses the current console when the remote system is an IP address, which is the only case where I can get redirection to pipes and files to work.