# How can i write this powershell cmdlet in perl script

Tags: perl, powershell

```
 invoke-command HOST01 { cmd /C dir /S /B D:\file1 }
```

How can i include this command in a perl script i tried using

`qx(invoke-command HOST01 { cmd /C dir /S /B D:\file1 })` it doesn't work ,the program runs forever.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770124/executing-powershell-from-perl?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

`invoke-command HOST01 { cmd /C dir /S /B D:\file1 }` isn't a shell (`cmd`) command. It's a PowerShell command, so you need to start by invoking PowerShell.

This is what you'd run from the command line:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-Command HOST01 { cmd /C dir /S /B D:\file1 }"
```

So you want:

```
qx{PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-Command HOST01 { cmd /C dir /S /B D:\file1 }"}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel confident that running an external program in Perl has been asked and answered many times.

```
my @output = qx(powershell -NoProfile -Command "icm HOST01 { gci -n -rec D:\\file1 }");

foreach my $line (@output) {
    print $line;
}
```

or

```
my $output = qx(powershell -NoProfile -Command "icm HOST01 { gci -n -rec D:\\file1 }");

print $output;
```

Comment: `foreach my $line ($output) { print $line; }` is better written as `print $output;`

Comment: that is the same command i mentioned in the question and i specifically told its not working , this is the output i get  , the name of the cmdlet  and its module name

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code and output. It is not possible to do this in comments.

Comment: @mob - I iterated over the output with the expectation that the OP would want to do something with the data.